# Why won't my background image render in the game view?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I'm trying to learn unity, and am currently working on what should be a very simple GameOver screen. However, it seems that the game over screen fails to render on the actual camera. I've attached screenshots of the inspector as most say this can be solved by changing the z position of the camera so that it's behind the background element, but this won't work for me. Any suggestions?

[image: Overall view w/ background element as inspector]

[image: View w/ camera as inspector]

Here are the only 3 scripts I'm using as well:

GameOver.cs (component of background)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameOver : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_Text wonLostText;
    public void Setup(int result) {
        gameObject.SetActive(true);
        // set text to won if won, lost if game lost
        if(result==1) {
            wonLostText.text = "You Won!";
        }
        else {
            wonLostText.text = "You Lost";
        }
    }

    public void PlayAgainButton() {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("GameScene");
    }
}
```

Controller.cs (component of controller)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Controller : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject card;
    public GameOver GameOverScreen;

    // create list to represent each different kind of card face (2 of each)
    List<int> faceIndexes = new List<int> {
        0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
        0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
        };

    public static System.Random rand = new System.Random();
    public int shuffle = 0;
    int[] visibleFaces = {-1, -1};

    // set distance each card will be from eachother
    float distance = 2.5f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        int startingLength = faceIndexes.Count;

        // starting position for the 2nd left card at the top from the left
        // and starting y position for the first row
        float yPosition = 3.75f;
        float xPosition = -1.25f; 

        // loop to place each card on the board
        for (int i=1; i<16; i+=1) {

            // shuffle cards each loop
            shuffle = rand.Next(0, (faceIndexes.Count));

            var temp = Instantiate(card, new Vector3(
                xPosition, yPosition, 0),
            Quaternion.identity);
            
            // set face
            temp.GetComponent<MainCard>().faceIndex = faceIndexes[shuffle];
            faceIndexes.Remove(faceIndexes[shuffle]);

            xPosition += distance;

            // simulate rows and cols
            if((i+1)%4==0) {
                xPosition = -3.75f;
                yPosition -= distance;
            }
        }
        card.GetComponent<MainCard>().faceIndex = faceIndexes[0];
    }

    // function to determine whether two cards have been flipped
    public bool TwoFaces() {
        bool cardsUp = false;
        if (visibleFaces[0] >= 0 && visibleFaces[1] >= 0) {
            cardsUp = true;
        }
        return cardsUp;
    }

    // add turned over face to visible faces array
    public void AddFace(int index) {
        if(visibleFaces[0] < 0) {
            visibleFaces[0] = index;
        }
        else if (visibleFaces[1] < 0) {
            visibleFaces[1] = index;
        }
    }

    // remove turned over card from visible faces array (flipped back)
    public void RemoveFace(int index) {
        if(visibleFaces[0] == index) {
            visibleFaces[0] = -1;
        }
        else if (visibleFaces[1] == index) {
            visibleFaces[1] = -1;
        }
    }

    // check if cards match
    public bool CardsMatch() {
        if(visibleFaces[0] == visibleFaces[1]) {
            visibleFaces[0] = -1;
            visibleFaces[1] = -1;
            return true;
        }
        print("Game Should Be Over");
        GameIsOver(0);
        return false;
    }

    // 
    public void GameIsOver(int result) {
        GameOverScreen.Setup(result);
    }

    void Awake()
    {
        card = GameObject.Find("Card");
    }
}
```

MainCard.cs (component of Card)

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MainCard : MonoBehaviour
{

    GameObject controller;
    SpriteRenderer renderer;

    // create face and back of card variables
    public Sprite[] faces;
    public Sprite back;
    public int faceIndex;
    public bool matched = false;

    public void OnMouseDown(){

        // only allow player to flip cards if there is not already a match
        if(matched == false) {

            if(renderer.sprite == back) {

                if(controller.GetComponent<Controller>().TwoFaces() == false) {
                    renderer.sprite = faces[faceIndex];
                    controller.GetComponent<Controller>().AddFace(faceIndex);
                    matched = controller.GetComponent<Controller>().CardsMatch();
                }

            }
            else {
                renderer.sprite = back;
                controller.GetComponent<Controller>().RemoveFace(faceIndex);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Awake() {
        renderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        controller = GameObject.Find("Controller");
    }
}```

As Already stated, I've tried moving the camera back further in order to show the background, but it won't seem to work. I am guessing this is a silly mistake that can be fixed with a single adjustment, just can't seem to find it myself and I've been trying to do so for hours. Any idea what is going on here?
````

Comment: is your Canvas a `Screenspace Overlay`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like background's RectTransform is out of the position and is placed at the bottom left corner of the Canvas. Set background's anchors properly and place the object itself at the center so it would fit the Canvas bounds.